# how to change port of JAX-RS services?

Tags: configuration, port, jax-rs, jboss7.x

I code a Java EE 6 with modular JAX-RS services on jboss 7.0, spring.
I find the web service port collision as jboss use port 8080 and the web service also use the port 8080. I want change my JAX-RS services port, but do not know where to configure it.

```
ERROR [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol] (MSC service thread 1-7) Error initializing endpoint: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind localhost/127.0.0.1:8080
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint.init(JIoEndpoint.java:983) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol.init(Http11Protocol.java:190) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.init(Connector.java:983) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.as.web.WebConnectorService.start(WebConnectorService.java:267) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0]
```

the restful application:

```
@ApplicationPath("resources")
public class MyRESTApplication extends Application {

private Set<Object> singletons = new HashSet<Object>();
private Set<Class<?>> empty = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
public MyRESTApplication(){
     singletons.add(new HelloWorldResource());
}
@Override
public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
     empty.add(HelloWorldResource.class);
     return empty;
}
@Override
public Set<Object> getSingletons() {

     return singletons;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the line  for the http port in standalone.xml located in directory \standalone\configuration.

If you want to find the application with which there is port conflict, run the command

netstat -ab on windows.
(or)
netstat -ap on Linux.